# Phenomenon of skin effect and explain about difference between alternating current and direct current?

Tags: electric-circuits

DC flows uniformly throughout the cross section of conductor while AC mainly flows through the outer surface area of conductor.This is known as SKIN EFFECT.Can you explain this from basic ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the value of current, that creates a changing magnetic field. A changing magnetic field induces an electric field. That electric field is the reason why voltage is induced in the wire. That voltage is pointing in the opposite direction of current flow in the middle of the wire and in the same direction on the sides of a wire. That means that the current in the middle Will be smaller and bigger by the sides.